# i bought a new car and its idling at 1000rpm

Tags: vw, golf

i bought a new 2019 Volkswagen golf 1.5 blue motion 130 hp with Dsg. i bought the car with 10 Miles. i drove home and realised it was idling at a very high rpm. i thought the car had to break in and i waited till 2000 miles. the car sometimes goes to the normal rpm which is 700-800 and it uses almost half of what it takes when idling at 1000 rpm. does someone know what could be the reason?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Is this when you start the car? Usually there's a cold start cycle that will idle a car at higher RPG until engine is warmed up, after that idle should be at it's usual low